# How to edit a text file in my terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, text-files

I'm using Linux mint and using the vi command to create text files, now that I created a text file and saved it. How do I get back into to edit the text file again?

```
vi helloWorld.txt
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Open the file again using vi. and then press the insert button to begin editing it.

Comment: Thank you, didn't think of that; I thought vi was only meant to create new files.

Comment: could also run 'vimtutor' to learn how to use vi/vim. This of course assumes you have vim (vi's big brother) if you don't run 'sudo apt-get install vim'

Answer (score 92):

Try this command:

```
sudo gedit helloWorld.txt
```

it, will open up a text editor to edit your file.

**OR**

```
sudo nano helloWorld.txt
```

Here, you can edit your file in the terminal window.

Comment: Thanks for "nano". I was searching my memory for its name.

Comment: I was looking in my notes for this command

Comment: nano is a lot better

Comment: Why do you need to use `sudo` for this?

Answer (score 53):

Open the file again using vi. and then press " i " or press insert key ,

For save and quit

```
  Enter Esc
```

and write the following command

```
  :wq
```

without save and quit

```
  :q!
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are still inside the vi editor, you might be in a different mode from the one you want. Hit ESC a couple of times (until it rings or flashes) and then "i" to enter INSERT mode or "a" to enter APPEND mode (they are the same, just start before or after current character).

If you are back at the command prompt, make sure you can locate the file, then navigate to that directory and perform the mentioned "vi helloWorld.txt". Once you are in the editor, you'll need to check the vi reference to know how to perform the editions you want (you may want to google "vi reference" or "vi cheat sheet").

Once the edition is done, hit ESC again, then type `:wq` to save your work or `:q!` to quit without saving.

For quick reference, [here](http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html) you have a text-based cheat sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the file again using `vi helloworld.txt` and then use `cat /path/your_file` to view it.

Answer (score 1):

**Another way to open a file is, by using `vim`**

Step 1: run command `vim FILENAME`

Step 2: Press `i` to edit

Step 3: If you want to save, press `esc` then enter `:wq` and hit enter

Step 4: If you don't want to save, press `esc` then enter `:q!`

**That's it.**

Answer (score -6):

To re-edit a file in your terminal using the vi command, you can follow these steps:

1. Open your terminal.
2. Use the following command to open the text file in vi: vi helloWorld.txt
3. Once the file is open, you can make any changes to the text.
4. To start editing, press the i key to enter insert mode. This allows you to type and edit the text.
5. After making your changes, press the Esc key to exit insert mode.
6. To save the changes and exit vi, type :wq (colon, w, q) and press Enter. This command saves the changes and quits vi.

Now, if you want to get back into the text file to edit it again, you can repeat the same command: vi helloWorld.txt. This will open the file in vi, and you can continue editing as before.
you doesn't have root access type this

```
sudo su
```

If you want to use nano editor to create oe edit file in same directory where you headed

1. `nano filename.format`

eg:- `nano helloWorld.txt`

2. `Ctrl+o`
3. ```
   Enter
   ```
4. ```
   Ctrl+x
   ```

If you want to use nano editor to file in other directory where you headed

1. ```
   nano location/filename.txt
   ```

eg1:- `nano Downloads/helloWorld.txt`

Comment: As I'm one of three persons to downvote this - First - I found this didn't seem to address the original question Second- and more importantly - you are for some reason suggesting that that user become root/super-user. 'sudo su' will open up more problems, and isn't necessary for this, and  you don't suggest why the questioner might do so.  Lots of unconnected facts, but no good answer, and at least one troublesome piece of advice. (Maybe you might revise this response?)

Comment: Why should `sudo` be neccessary, and why do you replace `vi` with `nano`?